# I am getting error when importing torch and torch vision

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I installed torch and torchvision using pip3 on MAC. When I imported the same, getting the below error.

Environment:

```
OS : macOS High Sierra
Python : 3.7
pip : 3
Pytorch 1.1
```

code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
```

Error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 import numpy as np
>         2 from glob import glob
>   ----> 3 import torch
>         4 import torchvision
>         5 from torchvision import datasets
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/**init**.py
>   in 
>        77 del _dl_flags
>        78 
>   ---> 79 from torch._C import *
>        80 
>        81 **all** += [name for name in dir(_C)
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-37m-darwin.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libshm.dylib
>   Reason: image not found

Any help on solving this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think

$ brew install libomp

can help u, cause i solve the same problem by it.

according

[github-issue-"libomp.dylib can't be loaded"](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/20030)